# Akka Design Principals

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

Whilst working on a fairly large Akka application, I have come across a very simple structure when working with normal methods and non-Akka classes but which are actually quite difficult to nail when working with Akka which is why I have come here to ask what you recommend to be the best way to solve this issue.

So the issue is this, I have one parent actor, let's call him "Connector", Connector has behavior describing what it should do when it receives a ConnectCommand instance. First, it submits a form using an HttpClient, then it goes to a couple of URLs to check for some session parameters and eventually sends the Sender (Referred to as the "Consumer") a connection message containing everything it needs to use the API.

Now, I'm a big fan of telling, not so much of pull / ask so implementing this is, in my opinion, a hard task to do. Let's go over it. All the responses returned by the HttpClientActor are a Response instance, so what first came to mind is having multiple behaviors defined in my actor and incrementally, after a certain step of the connection process has been completed, change behavior to the next step.

```
private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> inital = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(ConnectCommand.class, c -> this.startConnection())
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();

private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> stage1 = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(Response.class, this::stage1)
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();

private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> stage2 = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(Response.class, this::stage2)
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();

private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> stage3 = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(Response.class, this::stage3)
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();

private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> stage4 = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(Response.class, this::stage4)
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();

private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> stage5 = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(Response.class, this::stage5)
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();

private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> stage6 = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(Response.class, this::stage6)
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();

private final PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> stage7 = ReceiveBuilder
    .match(Response.class, this::stage7)
    .matchAny(this::unhandled)
    .build();
```

This has the advantage that it is using tell, not ask but has a major drawback that code becomes very unreadable.

Now I'm at the point I feel like this Actor needs some change in a good way but there are two alternatives in my opinion.

The first one involves splitting up every HttpRequest and Response into a separate Actor and aggregating the results in the Connector actor. This has the advantage of being very readable, using tell and shouldn't hurt performance because Akka is built to handle lots of actors. The only drawback to this is that I need to create a lot of container classes for these parts of state that need to be delivered from Stage5Actor to the Connector actor. This makes for a large memory overhead (correct me if I'm wrong).

The second approach is using the Ask pattern to wire the steps together. This would result in a single Connector actor and since Spray does so too for it's Http Client I think it may be a valid solution. The only drawback to this is, because everything rests on top of an external Http API, timeouts may become an issue. If this approach is recommended by the Akka team, how does one handle with all the timeouts which are completely unpredictable?

Please note that this implementation needs to be able to use supervision strategies since our whole current approach is based on top of this.

If you feel there is a far better solution than the ones I mentioned, please do tell! I'm really enjoying Akka a.t.m. and every piece of advice I get it, is a gain in experience and knowledge, not only for me but for the whole community :D. Plus I think this is an issue more people run into every once in a while.

Thanks in advance and a big thanks to the Akka team for producing such an awesome lib!

PS. This question was first asked on the Akka GitHub itself but I decided to post it here because this is just as much an Actor model related question as an Akka related question.

Link to the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like you don't necessarily need N stages to collect the responses. If you know how many responses you're waiting for you can collect them all under a single behavior.

Also, in any scenario where you are using `ask`, you can easily replace it with an intermediary Actor to hold this context and pass all messages through `tell`. That's actually what `ask` does anyway, but the main differences are that you wouldn't have to deal with specifying timeouts for every `ask` (well, you should still have a timeout for the overall request) and you can bundle all outstanding stages in a single Actor instead of an extra Actor for every `ask`.

Jamie Allen has really good description of this scenario as the [Extra and Cameo Patterns](http://www.slideshare.net/shinolajla/effective-akka-scalaio) in [Effective Akka](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028789.do).

So with all this in mind, you might be able to follow something along the lines of:

- When Consumer send the message to Connector, Connector can create a new Actor (Cameo) for this request context. You have to capture the `sender` Consumer in this Actor.
- The Cameo Actor can kick off the subsequent requests through `tell`s. At this point you can make either the Cameo or the Connector as the Supervisor so your Supervision Strategies still work as you want.
- The Cameo in it's `Receive` block can wait for responses from Connections. This doesn't have to be an `await` on the `ask`. Just accept the message in the `receive` and then update your internal state.
- When all the Connections are complete, you can respond to the original Consumer through `tell`.

Comment: Problem with this is, there is no real way for me to distinguish between the Response objects. Got any advice on that?

Comment: How do you mean? Do you want to map the Responses to the Requests?

Comment: Actually, if you use the intermediate actors as @CemCatikkas suggested, you can keep track of the responses that way. That is, for each message you want to send to client actor from the connector, create a new child actor that will send the actual message and then await the response. That intermediate actor can contain enough state to know to which request the response is in reply and pass that information back to the parent actor (the connector).

Comment: I bought the book Effective Akka and I must say, he knows his Akka. Thanks for the suggestion!